# Multiple if and vlookup conditions

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup

Hope you can help me.

So I have a situation here wherein I need to use 2 different data as a basis but I don't know how.

Please see attached picture.
The All Data tab is where all of the information is location
The two other tabs are per individual.

What I need is I want to get the AHT from All Data tab and put it in Mel's tab AHT column with a specific date.

Like for example, in 9/1/2022, I want to get Mel's AHT from All data tab.[Screenshot from Google Sheet][image: 1]

Comment: Please share data minimal example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-sheets-formula/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0):

if AHT column in all 3 sheets is C column and headers are in row 1...

```
=VLOOKUP(B2;  FILTER('All Data'!B:C; 'All Data'!A:A="Mel"); 2; 0)
```

and Nori sheet:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2;  FILTER('All Data'!B:C; 'All Data'!A:A="Nori"); 2; 0)
```